# Window Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I want to add a window functions.

Take the `min` date when visit = Y and end as Associd.

TableA

```
ID    Date      AssocId  Visit
 1     1/1/17    10101     Y
 1     1/2/17    10102     Y
```

End Results.

```
ID    Date    AssocId
 1    1/1/17    10101
```

SQL > This gives me the min date but I need the AssocId associated to that date.

```
 SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN A.VISIT = 'Y'
 THEN A.DATE END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) 
 AS MIN_DT,
```

Comment: Why are you using window functions?  If you only want one row, then aggregation makes more sense.

Comment: I was using window function to capure the min date but I want the associd associated to that min date. Not sure how to capture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
 SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN A.VISIT = 'Y' THEN A.DATE END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)  AS MIN_DT,
        FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN A.VISIT = 'Y' THEN A.ASSOCID END) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY A.VISIT DESC, A.DATE ASC),
```

Note that this is a little tricky with conditional operations.  I would be more inclined to use a subquery to nest the query operations.  The outer expression would be:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Date = MIN_DT THEN ASSOCID END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
```

If you wanted this per `ID`, I would suggest:

```
select id, min(date),
       first_value(associd) over (partition by id order by date)
from t
where visit = 'Y'
group by id;
```

That is, use aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
select t.*
from table t
where visit = 'Y' and
      date= (select min(t1.date) from table t1 where t1.id = t.id);
```